# Deleting specific element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have stumbled upon some weird solution, which allows to delete specific element of an array (static array).

Can some please explain to me how it actually works, since the explanation provided to an example isn't clear for me.

Here's the code. Let's say we have an array called **entryList**, and we want to delete the element which is specifically pointed by function called FindName.

```
void Directory::Remove()
{
   char aName[20];
   cout << "Type name to be removed";  
   cin.getline(aName, 20);

   int thisEntry = FindName(aName);

   if (thisEntry == -1)
      cout << aName << " not found in directory";
   else
   {
       /*** The bit that I don't understand ***/
       for (int j = thisEntry + 1; j < currentSize; j++)
           entryList[j - 1] = entryList[j];

    currentSize--;    
    cout << "Entry removed.\n";
   }
}
```

The explanation says that this 'algorithm' **will shift each succeding element "down" one position in the array, thereby deleting the desired entry.**

I did try to implement it on simple program but I couldn't make it work, can somebody please explain this particular method for me ?

Comment: Any reason for not using an `std::vector` or `std::list` ?

Comment: @quantdev: I know it's easier to use something from STL Collections, but I would love to understand this particular solution on standard static array.

Comment: You could provide at least definitions for things currentSize, entryList, etc.

Comment: The explanation seems to me like the simplest way to descibe the program. Perhaps you could show us the simple program you tried to implement (and the desired and observed result) and we can tell you why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is copying each element after the one being "deleted" into the position just before it (i.e. from position `j` to `j-1`).

Answer (score 0):

`FindName` returns index. If there is an element with your text (`aName`), it returns its index otherwise -1. So the for loop copies every element infront of found item, one block backward. Thus for example item at position 5 will go to 4. Using this algorithm, the found item will overwritten. Here is illustration:

Items at first:

[0] lion

[1] elephant

[2] penguin

Now we want to remove lion. `FindName` returns 0, because it's index is 0. So elephant goes to 0, penguin goes to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The program will search for provided name and return a position (such as a row in a file) in which the provided name exists. The position is stored in the thisEntry  variable. Then it will delete that row by assigning next name to that spot, and all names outside that row for the rest of currentSize - thisEntry elements. At the end it decrement the currentSize as only one entry has been removed. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Unroll the loop in your mind.

```
   /*** The bit that I don't understand ***/
   for (int j = thisEntry + 1; j < currentSize; j++)
       entryList[j - 1] = entryList[j];
```

Imagine that `thisEntry` is `15`.  And `currentSize` is `20`.

Then your loop is simply:

```
       entryList[15] = entryList[16]; // Copy entry 16 to entry 15
       entryList[16] = entryList[17]; // Copy entry 17 to entry 16
       entryList[17] = entryList[18]; // Copy entry 18 to entry 17
       entryList[18] = entryList[19]; // Copy entry 19 to entry 18
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember is that array in C/C++ are FIXED SIZE -- you cannot change the size on an array after it is created.  What you can do is change how the elements of the array are *used*.

In your example, you have an array `entryList` and a variable `currentSize` that tracks how much of the array is currently *used*.  This is *not* the size of the actual array -- its some number less than (or equal to) the size of the array that tracks how many elements in the array contain meaningful data.  Elements after this may exist, but their contents will not be used.

So when you remove an element from the array, you're not actually removing it from the array, you are replacing it (overwriting it) with the next element, and doing the same with all following elements, moving them all down one space in the array -- so the 'last' meaningful element in the array is duplicated.  You then decrement `currentSize`, making that duplicated last element "go away", as its now in the part of the array that will not be used.  The net overall effect is that the data in the *used* part of the array is one smaller than it used to be, and the element you deleted is gone, but all the others are present.